# Test google schema in my gmail account

Tags: google-schemas

I'm a starter in Google Schema, I've followed the getting started, but it doesn't work... I've changed to another more simple json-ld, simple actions, but ....
I'm testing with a Django project, in my local, django smtp config to smpt.gmail.com. Same from and to email. I can see the email, but I can't see go-to-action....
This is my original mail:

```
Return-Path: <XX@gmail.com>
Received: from tomas-H55M-D2H (37.130.151.22.radiocable.net. [37.130.151.22])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id n3sm2456222wix.1.2015.05.12.04.20.07
        for <XX@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 12 May 2015 04:20:07 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Testing
From: XX@gmail.com
To: XX@gmail.com
Date: Tue, 12 May 2015 11:20:07 -0000
Message-ID: <20150512112007.23123.78164@tomas-H55M-D2H>
Reply-To: XX@gmail.com

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context":       "http://schema.org",
      "@type":          "EmailMessage",
      "description":    "Check this out",
      "action": {
        "@type": "ViewAction",
        "url":   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eH8KwfdkSqU"
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      This a test for a Go-To action in Gmail.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to test if the markup produces the action button or not, try the Apps script tutorial: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial or this Smartmail generator: http://smartmailgenerator.appspot.com/

Comment: The body of mail is copy&paste from the example, and it works in script.google.com, but not with my python client...